# DOM nodes generate HTML5 Possible?

Tags: javascript, dom

**I want to generate a html5 file using DOM node methods, is it possible ?**

I already tried making but, i can't find the right code to generate with the 
"**!DOCTYPE**" template.

**I want like this structure :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
........
.......
.....
...
..
</html>
```

Comment: HTML is an input format. When you're operating on the DOM, HTML is not relevant any more.

Comment: Please post the code that you have already done so far. If you are looking for whether the doctype can be modified, it is not possible as doc type is `read-only` according this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/doctype

Comment: maybe you're thinking about generating an html string via AST?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can generate a <doctype> node, you'll just have to use [`document.implementation.createDocumentType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocumentType) method.

However, to generate an HTML5 document is quite a burden (at least when it comes to stringification). Indeed, there is no HTML5 namespace, and your HTML5 document is actually XHTML once parsed in the DOM:

```js
console.log(document.documentElement.namespaceURI);
```

So when you'll stringify this document, you'll have the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attributes all over your elements.

To avoid that, you actually need to generate all your elements with a `null` namespace:

```js
// Our <!DOCTYPE html> node
const doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', ''); 
// A new HTML5 document
const doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", 'html', doctype);

// We need to force null NS
const body = doc.createElementNS(null, 'body');
body.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('hello'));

doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);

const str = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Do you know, why Chrome still runs in `Quirks-Mode` after adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>`? 